# Pass json string as a parameter into ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass JSON string into ng-click

here is the JSON string:

```
{"id":0,"parentID":0,"SubMenuItems":[],"imageName":"Icon.png","moduleName":"No Menu"}
```

**HTML:**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button ng-click="go({
      "id": 0,
      "parentID": 0,
      "SubMenuItems": [],
      "imageName": "Icon.png",
      "moduleName": "No Menu"
    })">GOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS:**
// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.go = function(parm) {
      alert('hi');
    };
  }
]);
```

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfCvWGWJXKPY51fz72nC?p=preview)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that you need to declare `ngController` directive `ng-controller="appCtrl"` on some element. The second one is that you have to take `ngClick` attributes in quotes and then pass object without quotes into `go` function. Angular will understand that you are passing and object:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button ng-click='go({
      "id": 0,
      "parentID": 0,
      "SubMenuItems": [],
      "imageName": "Icon.png",
      "moduleName": "No Menu"
    })'>GOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!</button>
</body>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/8WuuhbCaZBom05ep576K?p=preview